# Multiple “from:” keywords in Outlook advanced search

Tags: search, outlook

I've tried this every way I can think of. Scenario: you have an inbox with five emails, each from a different person: *personA*, *personB*, ... *personE*. My goal is to write a search query that excludes people and shows the remaining emails.

I can write positive queries like `from:personA OR from:personB`, and the query returns a mixed bag of emails from *personA* and *personB*.

I've written the converse query `NOT (from:personA OR from:personB)` and the query returns all emails including *personA* and *personB*. I've tried variants like `NOT from:personA AND NOT from:personB`, `NOT from:personA OR NOT from:personB` and nothing works.

If I reduce the query to exclude only one person, it works as expected. However, if I try to expand scope to exclude more than one it doesn't returned desired results. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you talking about outlook.com or the desktop app?

Comment: Referring to Desktop app

Comment: Will you accept an answer that involves using the GUI to generate a query, or do you require typing in a query into the search field?

Comment: I prefer the latter.  Are you saying it's not possible via query in search box?

Comment: @japollock I have tried typing all sorts of combinations into the search field and nothing works.  Seems like a bug in Outlook to be honest.  But there's a way to do it using the GUI.